# Is 'love' transitive?

Tags: english, verbs, transitivity, complement, valency

I was just watching a linguistics video in which it was stated that in the sentence "John loves Mary", the verb *love* requires the direct object *Mary*, implying that it would be incorrect to say simply "John loves". Now, what if I, a native speaker of English, disagree with this assertion? I think "John loves" is a perfectly good sentence. It means he loves *in general*.

Similarly, I think the sentence "I am" is complete, without any complement. I've seen this sentence often enough and it means *I exist*.

Now, I can foresee your responses: sentences such as "I am" and "John loves" are spiritual and poetic. So what if they are? Is the aim of linguistics to ban poetry?

I don't mean to be antagonistic, but I'm having some difficulty penetrating into the linguistic way of thinking.

A side note: I have seen it written in several places that a verb can be "both transitive and intransitive". How can this be? If a transitive verb is a verb that accepts an object, and an intransitive verb is one that does not, then these categories are mutually exclusive.

Comment: _Love_ is an example of a verb that is both transitive and intransitive, meaning it can be used both with and without an object. A verb cannot be _used_ both transitively and intransitively at the same time – that would indeed be a contradiction in terms – but there’s nothing mutually exclusive about one use of a verb being transitive and another intransitive.

Comment: Is there a resource where I can look up the transitivity or intransitivity of different verbs?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The word 'accepts' in the definition of transitivity (that I got from Wikipedia) makes it sound like it covers all possible cases: a transitive verb CAN HAVE an object, and an intransitive verb CAN NEVER have an object. Otherwise, we should define transitivity like so: a transitive verb is one that HAS an object (in a particular sentence). Do you see what I'm saying?

Comment: Most dictionaries will show transitivity for each verb in one way or another. In a given usage, a transitive verb will indeed be one that HAS an object. As an inherent property of the verb itself, ‘transitive’ normally means that it CAN have an object, because the vast majority of transitive verbs can also be used intransitively; few verbs are exclusively transitive.

Comment: Worth mentioning that some linguists nowadays consider "transitive" and "intransitive" to be properties not of verbs but of constructions. In English, very many (maybe most?) verbs can enter into both constructions, though they may have a preference for one or the other. (BTW, the example "I am" isn't relevant to transitivity, because a complement isn't an object.)

Comment: Note though that there are indeed verbs which can only be used transitively and not intransitively: Cf. *John devoured a stake* vs. *\* John devoured*.

Comment: Some would analyse "John loves" as transitive with an elided object. It always has implied object(s) in a way that a true intransitive verb like "John jumps" does not.

Comment: I guess you're right @curiousdannii.

Comment: I just think the terms transitive/intransitive are not sufficient to distinguish all the different cases: some verbs can take an object, some cannot, and some do sometimes. That's 3 different cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's even more complicated than that, because some verbs can take two objects: I gave Joe the book.

Comment: You have to consider the uses of the verb. "John loves" is intransitive since there is no object, while "John loves Mary" is transitive since "loves" has the object "Mary". The rule is: no object = intransitive -- simple as that!

Comment: @curiousdannii That’s just passing the buck, though, and not in a way that makes anything better, as far as I can tell. What’s the basis for the assumption that intransitive uses of _jump_ are true intransitives with no implied object, while intransitive uses of _love_ are actually transitive with an implied object? Both verbs can be used transitively and intransitively, so for this analysis to work, there must be some other property that distinguishes them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I meant the basic sense of jumping, not other senses like attacking or the sexual sense. I don't see how the basic sense could be transitive.

Comment: @curiousdannii The basic sense can be used transitively too, with the object being a type of jumping motion (‘she jumped a backflip’ – though _do_ would be more common here), a hurdle (‘the horse jumped the first jump but balked at the second’), a distance (‘he jumped 7.83 metres’), or various other things.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The only one of those I think is the same basic sense is the distance. But that does count, so you've convinced me! But there are other examples of fundamentally intransitive verbs. *Sleep* maybe? But maybe there are transitive constructions of *sleep* I haven't thought of...

Comment: @curiousdannii Certainly – we can sleep the sleep of the just, after all.

Answer (score -4):

In the above sentence, “I gave Joe the book,” while there are two (2) objects, Joe is considered the indirect object & the book the direct object.

Re “love” being intransitive, I saw a sample that read something like, ‘Pete loves the coffee shop’s hours/offerings.’  I suppose b/c the hours/offerings can’t feel/truly receive Pete’s love, it’s considered intransitive here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, “Pete loves the coffee shop’s hours/offerings” is quite unambiguously transitive. The ability of the object to feel Pete’s love is irrelevant to its grammatical status as direct object. Not sure how ditransitive constructions are particularly relevant here.

Comment: Direct object indeed, however the hours/offerings can’t truly receive his love as they have no idea what’s even going on b/c they’re non living.  (There are serious issues to concern ourselves w/, so won’t engage further. My intent here was to simply offer a different perspective to assist re the initially-posed question, which I successfully did.)

Comment: The animacy or awareness of the object plays no role at all for transitivity in English (though it might in some other languages). That’s semantics, not grammar.